# How to store a magic number for each derived class that is then accessible from the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, constants

```
class User {
    public:
        int v() {
            return min_pass_len;
        }
        static const int min_pass_len = 10;
};
class AdminUser : public User {
    public:
        int w() {
            return min_pass_len;
    }

    static const int min_pass_len = 42;
};
```

Then

```
int main() {
    AdminUser a;
    std::cout << a.v()  << " why? " << a.w() <<  std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can I somehow avoid the extra method call? I'm also interested in other solutions, best practices. Thanks!

Comment: Which 'extra' method call do you want eliminate? I can't quite understand what you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a virtual method that returns a different number, skip the static var.

```
class User {
    public:
        virtual int v() {
            return 10;
        }
};

class AdminUser : public User {
    public:
        virtual int v() {
            return 42;
    }    
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted it, as this is really the simplest, no need for templates (not that I'm against them) and even if this exchanges the static members to function calls, but performance wise it's truly  negligible. (And as a small bonus, this even works!)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a different constant for different derived classes, you should templatize the base class like so:

```
template<class T>
class User 
{
    // Make the password len getter virtual.
    virtual GetPassLen() { return min_pass_len; }
    ...
    static const int min_pass_len = 10;
}

class AdminUser : public User<AdminUser>
{
}

// All admin users get this constant
AdminUser::min_pass_len = 42;

class GuestUser : public User<GuestUser>
{
}

// Guest user can have a different constant than Admin user.
Guestuser::min_pass_len = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `virtual` keyword.  In C++ methods are not virtual by default like they are in some other programming languages (e.g., Java).  Try the following instead:

```
#include <iostream>

class User {
    static const int min_pass_len = 10;
public:
    virtual ~User() {}
    virtual int getPasswordLength() const {
        return min_pass_len;
    }
};

class AdminUser: public User {
    static const int min_pass_len = 42;
public:
    virtual ~AdminUser() {}
    virtual int getPasswordLength() const {
        return min_pass_len;
    }
};

int
main()
{
    AdminUser a;
    User u, *p = &a;
    std::cout
        << u.getPasswordLength() << "\n"
        << a.getPasswordLength() << "\n"
        << p->getPasswordLength() << "\n"
        << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to get rid of the method altogether, then either use the example of the [*"curiously reoccuring template pattern"* mentioned by Sanjit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481285/how-to-store-a-magic-number-for-each-derived-class-that-is-then-accessible-from-t/4481363#4481363) or externalize the constant instead embedding it within the class.  I was thinking of something similar to how `std::numeric_limits` is implemented:

```
template <typename T>
struct UserTraits {
    static const int minimum_password_length = 0;
};

template<> struct UserTraits<User> {
    static const int minimum_password_length = 10;
};
template<> struct UserTraits<AdminUser> {
    static const int minimum_password_length = 10;
};

int main() {
    std::cout
        << UserTraits<User>::minimum_password_length << "\n"
        << UserTraits<AdminUser>::minimum_password_length << "\n"
        << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I usually prefer the first approach since it works when you have a pointer to an instance.  The latter method isn't nearly as useful since you cannot use it to extract the constant from an instance without resorting to writing a free function and even then you loose the dynamic typed aspect.

```
template <typename T>
int getPasswordLength(T*) {
    return UserTraits<T>::minimum_password_length;
}
template <typename T>
int getPasswordLength(T&) {
    return UserTraits<T>::minimum_password_length;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that you would get the wrong result if you called `getPasswordLength(p)` using `p` in the first snippet.

Answer (score 1):

*Best practices* would recommend use of `virtual` function (this is why they were introduced, to make old code able to call new code):

```
class base{
public:  virtual int get_magic(){return 10;};
};

class der1: public base{
public:  virtual int get_magic(){return 42;};
};
```

Howerer, a simple variable defined in the base class, but rewritten in each derived constructor would be faster and would eliminate any call (since it would be inlined):

```
class base{
protected:  int magic; // note that it's not static!
public:
    base(){magic = 10;};
    int get_magic(){return magic;};
};

class der1: public base{
public:
    der1(){magic = 42;};
};
```

Comment: Could modern compilers optimize away the integer member from instances? (Implicitly make it a class variable.)

Comment: @PAStheLoD: It can't be optimized away, and it's the price you have to pay for speed. It would be possible only if you could declare it as `virtual int magic`, something that is impossible in C++. However, by having at least 1 virtual function in the class its size grows by size of pointer.

Comment: @PAStheLoD: check this article, it covers the subject with LOTS of details: http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/dispatch.html